# how to add one array element to another array. for example add ganguly to arrayA and delete sachin there

Tags: javascript, json

```
 var arrayA = [ {"name":"sachin","location":"mum"} ]; 
 var arrayB = [ {"name":"Ganguly","location":"mum"} ]; 
 var newArray = arrayA.push(JSON.stringify((arrayB[0].name)));
 console.log(newArray); console.log(arrayA);`
```

Comment: you can use array.splice function.

Comment: please edit my example

Comment: sorry bro its not correctly replace with sachin ...its replace sachin but its also replace loacation plz check once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you dont want to create new array then:

```
var arrayA = [ {"name":"sachin","location":"mum"} ]; 
var arrayB = [ {"name":"Ganguly","location":"mum"} ]; 
arrayA[0].name = arrayB[0].name;
console.log(arrayA);`
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it's an object array and assuming more than one element in future, you need to filter out ganguly object and add it to newArray, and to remove sachin object, you can use the same filter function.

```
var gangulyArr = arrayB.filter(function(el) {
    return el.name === "Ganguly";
});

var newArray  = arrayA.concat(gangulyArr);//gangulyArr has all objs named 
 // ganguly, even if its one

arrayA = arrayA.filter(function(el) {
    return el.name !== "sachin"; // to remove sachin from original array
});
```

If you want to write less code, prefer [underscore](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/), it has great methods for these - find, remove, reject, pluck etc.,

```
 var gangulyObj =  _.find(arrayB, 'name', 'Ganguly');
 var newArray = arrayA;
 if(gangulyObj) {
     newArray.push(gangulyObj);
 }

 arrayA = _.reject(arrayA , function(el) { return el.name === "sachin"; });
```

Comment: thank u so much bro...its working. could you please tell me how to use underscorejs

Comment: Download underscore.js and include that in your project.
use this link to start with it https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-cozy-with-underscorejs--net-24581
there are many resources online. Here's the documentation http://underscorejs.org/#reject